# How to use a certificate authority (CA) with a separate key file for SSL bumping in squid 4.x?

Tags: proxy, ssl, certificate, squid

According to [the squid article on SSL bumping](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DynamicSslCert) one uses the `cert` parameter of the `http_port [port] ssl-bump` directive in order to specify a CA which has it's key included in one file (protected by OS file access permissions). I'd like to reuse an existing CA which has it's key stored in a separate file which thus needs to be specified (I assume in a separate parameter).

I don't find more than this article on the topic at all.

I'm using squid 4.0.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looking just a little bit further (one click) from the article you refer to one will find the [documentation of all parameters](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/http_port/) usable for `http_port`, which includes:

```
key=    Path to SSL private key file (PEM format)
        if not specified, the certificate file is
        assumed to be a combined certificate and
        key file.
```